# Accessing hardware with Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, android-source

I need to extend the functionality of the android.hardware.Camera class and so I have written my own class and companion JNI library to meet my needs. If I place my JNI code and Android.mk file in the Android source tree and build the OS, my library builds and I can use it and the Java class in an application without any problems (on an evaluation module at least).

The problem is that I would prefer to build my JNI library with the NDK but I need several libraries that are not in the NDK (e.g. libandroid_runtime and libcamera_client).

Is it possible to use the NDK to access hardware such as the camera? If so, what is the proper way to get access to OS libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can access non-standard shared libraries from NDK, but that is undocumented and is not guaranteed to work on different devices. Vendors like HTC, Samsung and other can simply implement them differently.

Only proper way how to use functionality not available in NDK is to wrap it with Java classe/functions, and then use them from native code.